# Google Sheet Conditional HideColumn() & ShowColumn()

Tags: google-apps-script

Appreciate if someone can help me out with this chunk of codes. What I am trying to achieve (step by step) is:

1. If Checkbox in Cell "A7" is checked in Sheet1
2. Column "P" will be automatically be unhidden in Sheet2
3. Else if Checkbox in Cell "A7" is unchecked in Sheet 1
4. Column "P" will be automatically be hidden in Sheet2

This is my 1st time doing coding....really grateful if a kind soul can help. Thanks.

```
function showHide() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");
  var vtrue = "TRUE"
  var vfalse = "FALSE"

  sheet1.getRange('A7').activate();

  if (sheet1.getRange('A7').getValue() == vtrue)  {
    sheet2.showColumns(sheet2.getRange("P:AA"));  
  } else if (sheet1.getRange('A7').getValue() == vfalse)   {
    sheet2.hideColumns(sheet2.getRange("P:AA"));
  }       
}
```

Thanks a million.

Cheers.

Comment: what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Consider reviewing the Apps Script "Simple Trigger" documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right API to hide columns is `sheet2.hideColumns(columnIndex, numOfColumns)` - both parameters are numbers.
You can see it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex) .

There is good trick to learn how thinks works.

- Go to menu->tools->Macros (New).
- Do the action you want to do programmatically (click, hide-column, etc.)
- Go to script editor - you'll see there the script :-)

Comment: [`Sheet#hideColumn`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideColumn(Range)) (note the lack of `s` at the end) takes a `Range` argument

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for the tips! It helped. I have finally gotten the function working.

```
function showHide() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");

  sheet1.getRange('A7').activate();

  if (sheet1.getRange('A7').getValue() == true)  {
    sheet2.showColumns(16,2);      
    } else {
    sheet2.hideColumns(16,2);    
  }   
}
```

Instead of getting var result from checkbox, it is already a boolean. Nosyara is right, the showColumns() API require number parameters to indicate the column(s) to hide or show.

Many thanks again!